# CodeIgniter Controller with two forms

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a Controller Function Called "UpdateAccountDetails".  It updates parent table and child table. Parent Table is Account and Child Table is Accountleads. user can CRUD on child table.

There are three Views are: UpdateAccountDetails.php and CreateAccountleadInsertPOPUP.php,CreateAccountleadUpdatePOPUP.php,CreateAccountleadDeletePOPUP.php

I was wondering , how do I code the controller? Any pointer will help.

```
    public function  CreatePatientDetails( )
    {

                if (($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') = 'POST')&& ($this->input->post('form_id') = 'CreatePatientDetails_AccountInsert'));
                {
                    //call model                       

                 } // End of Insert on Account

                if (($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') = 'POST')&& ($this->input->post('form_id') = 'CreatePatientDetails_AccountleadsInsert'));
                {                         
                    //call model                       

                 } // End of Insert on Accountleads

                if (($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') = 'POST')&& ($this->input->post('form_id') = 'CreatePatientDetails_AccountleadsUpdate'));
                {


                 } // End of Update on Accountleads

                if (($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') = 'POST')&& ($this->input->post('form_id') = 'CreatePatientDetails_AccountleadsDelete'));
                {


                 } // End of Delete on Accountleads



                $data['Accountleads'] = $this->Accountleads_model->AccountleadsGetAll($objAccountleads); 

                $data['main_content'] = 'MasterDataMgtviews/CreatePatientDetails'; 
                $this->load->view('includes/template', $data); 



    }
```

Comment: take a few minutes and do the tutorial http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html basically you are going to call form validation, and if it passes then you will interact with the database.

Comment: With form_hidden I was able to get it. However, not sure what else is missing in Controller function to able to do CRUD on child table.

Comment: Try something simpler to start. If you still can't figure it out then using a simpler example post all of your code - controller, model and views - and the specific error message. otherwise its impossible to help which is why you didn't get any replies